# Special char not recognized in String class

Tags: java, string, special-characters

### This is a solution to an error with java.String.indexOf(char)

I have been working on algorithms for a logic calculator and some of the commonly accept logic characters weren't being detected by the **String** class (ie `⇔` was not detected when `String.indexOf("⇔");` was called)

I was able to create a solution and I am posting it here to help others with similar problems.

```
/* 
 * Compares the decimal value of each char to the decimal value of the char
 * that isn't detected by java.String 
 */

   String string = "any char with ⇔ decimal value";         
   int[] charAsDecimal = new int[string.length() -1];
   int locationOfSpeicalChar = 0;

   for(int x = 0; x < string.length(); x++)
   {
       charAsDecimal[x] = (int)string.charAt(x);
   }
   for(int x = 0; x < string.length(); x++)
   {
       if(charAsDecimal[x] == 8660)
       {
           System.out.println("⇔ is at index value " + x);
           locationOfSpeicalChar = x;
       }
   }

   System.out.println(string);
   string = string.substring(locationOfSpeicalChar);
   System/out.println(string);

   /*
    * ⇔ in decimal is 8660 and can be used to find in charAsDecimal. The index value
    * in charAsDecimal is the same index value as in string.
    */
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: What is `E` in `E.charAt`? Did you mean `string` instead?

Comment: Why allocate the space for int[]  a = new int[string.length()-1];
? Why not just: System.out.println("value at " + x + " : " + string.charAt(x) + " in dec = " + (int)E.charAt(x));

Comment: `These values are then [...] (not included)` A Solution is most helpful to other people when it's complete.

Comment: `indexOf` is working fine finding the given character/String ('⇔' = '\u21D4') so there must be something else not working... BTW there is no need to convert a `char` to `int` just to compare it to another `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first , there is no need to write `string.length()-1` , with this approach you are losing one character

second , i didn't know what is `E` in this code , it is not defined here , probably you need to convert the `char` array to `int` array , try this way :

```
String string = "any char with decimal value";       
int[]  a = new int[string.length()];

for(int x = 0; x < string.length() ; x++){
    a[x] = (int)string.charAt(x);
    System.out.println("value at " + x + " : " + string.charAt(x) + " in dec = " + a[x]);
}
```

Comment: That is a type. String E was the variable I used when I was working on this problem

Comment: The code posted is the answer to the problem I was having. I posted it here as a question but stated that the code posted was a solution to an error I encountered with java.String in the event that other developers encounter the same problem and don't have a solution